# How to determine the number to the right of decimal in a floating point number?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have searched the entire Stack Overflow site and couldn't find a single post about determining the right part of a floating point number using MySQL.

Suppose I have a floating point number such as 3.1416. All I need is a MySQL function that will return 1416.

I have tried using the `SUBSTRING` function of MySQL but the problem is: this solution is not dynamic.

Suppose, for a column named `constant_value` in a table named `Physics`, I use the following query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(constant_value, 2) FROM Physics
```

For 3.1416, it will return 1416, but for 21.436, it will return 1.436. But I want it to return 436.

**EDIT:**

Tried both [Andrew Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1115360/andrew-morton) and [Rafiq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151290/rafiq) Vai's solution. Both returns the same output.

It seems I was unable to explain my problem in the question. It isn't really the mantissa I'm looking for. It's the text to the right of the decimal point what I want.

If `constant_value` = 3.1416, I want a MySQL function that will return 1416, not 0.1416. Andrew and Rafiq Vai's solutions give me 0.1416, while I'm looking for 1416.

Comment: what are you trying to do? There may be other ways.

Comment: That's what I want to know. I don't have the slightest of idea how to do this.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. If you can't explain the problem, how do you know you have a problem. Walk us through your code, procedure. What do you have, what do you need?

Comment: You can get mantisa by `floating number-abs(floating number)` i.e  `5.6-abs(5.6)` = `0.6`

Comment: BTW, I'm looking for yet better solutions. Is there any?

Comment: 436 is not the mantissa of 21.436. What are you *really* asking for?

Comment: @All, question edited.

Comment: @Rafiq What about negative numbers?

Comment: @Rafiq You're on the right track but you're using the same wrong terminology as the OP.

Comment: @ Andrew Morten For negative number this can be used `ABS(-3.14)-FLOOR(ABS(-3.14))`

Comment: @siride as opposed to the good old days? the golden age? What exactly is your point?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT abs(constant_value)-floor(abs(constant_value)) FROM Physics
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from MySQL 3.23.51 (because, starting from that version, the function in effect rounds toward zero), you can use the [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) function:

```
SELECT constant_value - TRUNCATE(constant_value, 0) FROM Physics
```